# digital ocean build field , how to modify build command?

Tags: node.js, deployment, digital-ocean, mern, digital-ocean-apps

I am attempting to upload my MERN app, however, I am encountering an error while deploying:

```
sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
[2023-06-18 00:10:15] [1]  npm run client exited with code 127
[2023-06-18 00:10:15] --> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[2023-06-18 00:10:16] [0] npm run server exited with code SIGTERM
```

This is my `package.json` code snippet. I am using the command `npm run setup-production` to build my application:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-client": "cd client && npm run build",
    "server": "nodemon server --ignore client",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \" npm run client\"",
    "setup-production": "npm run install-client && npm run build-client && npm install",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install"
  },
```

I need help running `setup-production` inside Digital Ocean. Can anyone assist me?